# Convert a string slice to a BSON array

Tags: mongodb, go, type-conversion, mongo-go

I am trying to insert an array into a MongoDB instance using Go. I have the `[] string` slice in Go and want to convert it into a `BSON` array to pass it to the DB using the `github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver` driver.

```
var result bson.Array
    for _, data := range myData {
        value := bson.VC.String(data)
        result.Append(value)
}
```

This loops over each element of my input data and tries to append it to the `BSON` array. However the line with the `Append()` fails with `panic: document is nil`. How should I do this conversion?

Comment: have you tried the `NewArray()`? See the example https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson#example-Array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: The code in the question and this answer is no longer relevant because the bson.Array type was deleted from the package. At the time of this edit, the [bson.A](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson#A) and basic slice operations should be used to construct arrays.

Use the factory function [NewArray](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson#NewArray) to create the array:

```
result := bson.NewArray()
for _, data := range myData {
        value := bson.VC.String(data)
        result.Append(value)
}
```

Comment: This no longer appears to work and your NewArray link just goes to the top of the documentation page.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Cerise bson.Array has since been deleted. I do this with multiple utility functions as follows:

```
func BSONStringA(sa []string) (result bson.A) {
  result = bson.A{}
  for_, e := range sa {
    result = append(result, e)
  }
  return
}

func BSONIntA(ia []string) (result bson.A) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting a slice of string (`ids`) to BSON array

```
var objIds bson.A
for _, val := range ids {
    objIds = append(objIds, val)
}
log.Println(objIds)
```